# Extract rar file with php failed with warning

Tags: php

I just install php rar extension and test it with below sample from http://www.php.net/manual/en/rar.examples.php

But failed, filenames was printed out,however no file was extraced,I saw waring:~

> warning: RarEntry::extract() [rarentry.extract]: ERAR_ECREATE in

```
<?php

$rar_file = rar_open('example.rar') or die("Can't open Rar archive");

$entries = rar_list($rar_file);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo 'Filename: ' . $entry->getName() . "\n";

    $entry->extract('/dir/extract/to/');
}

rar_close($rar_file);

?>
```

I searched for a while via google but without luck. What's going wrong? thank you !

> I solved it by myself already.
>
> it is due to destination folder permission I give the folder 777 ,then
>   it works.

Comment: checked path to extract to, check permissions. only things i can think of.

Comment: add your solution as an answer, not in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer was originaly posted as an Edit by the author**

> I solved it by myself already. 
>   it is due to destination folder permission I give the folder 777 ,then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please DO NOT give that folder 777 permission. But rather change the owner of the folder the user running the php command. In my case the directory was owned by `root` and php ran on the apache server's user. What I did was:

`chown user:user my_directory`